# How to set the provider for OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-session, spring-authorization-server

How can I set the provider class for OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken object.

I am working on springboot using spring security 5 and Spring Authorization Server ver 0.3.1
I already make the configuration of both but still I encounter this error.

Can anybody provide some sample links on how to do such.

Error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:234)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Configuring Client Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/0.3.1/reference/html/configuration-model.html#configuring-client-authentication) in the reference.

Comment: thank you. But I realize this is not what is happening in my code. Sorry for this as I am trying to understand the spring authorization server. I created a new question, this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680739/spring-authorization-server-no-authenticationprovider-found-for-oauth2authoriza