# Spring Authorization Server: No AuthenticationProvider found for OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I am coding using Spring Security 5.5 and Spring Authorization Server ver 0.3.1

I want to use a custom authentication provider to get the principal with a custom LoginUser class.

I named my custom authentication provider class as CustomAuthProvider, its instance is `customAuthProvider`

In my Spring Authorization config class I defined this filter chain:

```
@Bean
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer =
      new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();
    RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer
      .getEndpointsMatcher();

    http
      .requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
      .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
      )
      .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
      .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);

    authorizationServerConfigurer
      .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint ->
        authorizationEndpoint
          .authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider)
      );

    http.exceptionHandling(
        (exceptions) ->
            exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")));

    return http.build();
}
```

When I run my code, I cannot get a token because I get this error:

```
ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken
```

I dont understand why is this.

I already set the provider in the filterchain but I still got this error.

Maybe anybody out there encounter this kind of predicament.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1) You have oauth2 server configurer, why do u need custom `customAuthProvider` why can't you use a existing implementation of `AuthenticationProvider`. 2) `authorizationEndpoint` configuration is after of `apply` of configurer. Put that before apply.

Comment: In oauth2 transaction, first the user will authenticate by logging-in using username and password. This username, and password information, I saved this in a LoginUser class that implements UserDetails. And this class is handled in the customAuthProvider. This LoginUser object will become the Principal...when I request to an endpoint, I am expecting that with @AuthenticationPrincipal annotated on a loginUser variable, I can get the LoginUser object carrying the user and password info....but what happen is the value is null....

Comment: If you only want to customize the user details class, just provide your own user details service as a bean. You don’t need an entire authentication provider for this case.

Comment: I have a class LoginUser that implements UserDetails. I also have a class CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider that extends DaoAuthenticationProvider. In authorization code grant type, when logging in, the usrname and password is set in the LoginUser w/c is done inside CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider. The expected result is that LoginUser will become a Principal of the authentication. In the endpoint method, the @AuthenticationPrincipal annotated parameter wil be able to get the LoginUser....but what I get is null causing an NPE when I assume a LoginUser was the value.

Answer (score 0):

@jetpack Did the issue resolve for you?
I think the issue would be with the http auth setting. It looks like you have given multiple source of information per se.
http.authorize and authorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationEndpoint these maybe conflicting.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35195551)